# Parsing HTML with Nokogiri - The Ruby/Rails Way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coding-style, nokogiri

I'm making a small Rails application to parse an HTML playlist from a local public radio station and display the currently playing song.

I've created a class to model the songs on the playlist that looks like this:

```
require 'open-uri'

class Song

  attr_accessor :artist, :title, :album, :playtime

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def self.latest(how_many)
    html = Nokogiri::HTML(open(Rails.configuration.on_air_url))
    rows = html.css('#table_tracklist tbody tr')
    rows.take(how_many).map do |row|
      parse_song(row)
    end
  end

  private

  def self.parse_song(row)
    artist = row.css('.artist').text
    playtime = row.css('.time span').text
    title = row.css('.song').text
    album = row.css('.album').text
    Song.new({ artist: artist, playtime: playtime, title: title, album: album })
  end

end
```

I have a couple of questions about this:

1. I'm not using any of the ActiveRecord or ActiveModel features.  Does this still belong as a class in my `models` directory or should I refactor it to a class in `lib`?  I was planning on having a controller whose only purpose will be to return the latest songs played via JSON to the client.  Is there a better way?
2. I'm happy with the `Song::latest` method, but I feel like there should be a more elegant way to do `Song::parse_song`.  I'm thinking of changing my model's attributes to match the names of the CSS classes the playlist uses and using an array of attribute names I want to grab, but since there is the special case of the "time" field (where I want to grab the text of the span) it seems like it would be more clear this way.  Could you offer some suggestions?

I think removing my initialize method and doing something like this would be better.  Thoughts?  [note: incorporates The Tin Man's answer below.]

```
  def self.parse_song(row)
    song = Song.new
    song.artist = row.at_css('.artist').text
    song.playtime = row.at_css('.time span').text
    song.title = row.at_css('.song').text
    song.album = row.at_css('.album').text
    song
  end
```

Comment: In general your question is too broad. [so] wants questions with a single issue to be solved, but two related questions are OK. Nokogiri use, and how you build a Rails app are not closely related. Also, asking a technical question of using Nokogiri is on-topic. Asking general philosophical questions about designing your classes becomes more nebulous and leads to opinions, not facts, which puts the question on the path of being off-topic for Stack Overflow, and on-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: Also, it's not useful, or necessary, to put in "edit:". We can see your chain of edits if we need to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't understand what [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css) does:

```
artist = row.css('.artist').text
playtime = row.css('.time span').text
title = row.css('.song').text
album = row.css('.album').text
```

Which should be:

```
artist = row.at('.artist').text
playtime = row.at('.time span').text
title = row.at('.song').text
album = row.at('.album').text
```

[`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css), like [`search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search) and [`xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) returns a [NodeSet](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html). A NodeSet is like an array of [Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html)s. Even if you know there is only one matching element in the document, `css` will still return a set. If there are multiple hits for a particular selector, you're going to receive all nodes that match.

When you use `text` on a NodeSet you're going to get a concatenated string of all the text in the nodes, which is most likely not what you want:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.css('p').text # => "foobar"
```

Also, Nokogiri is very forgiving/understanding when it comes to the code we use to talk to it. We don't have to use [`css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-css), or [`xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath), we can use [`search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search) and let Nokogiri figure out whether the selector is CSS or XPath:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.css('p').size # => 2
doc.search('p').size # => 2
```

The same is true for [`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at), [`at_css`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_css) and [`at_xpath`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at_xpath):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<html>
  <body>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
  </body>
</html>
EOT

doc.at_css('p').text # => "foo"
doc.at('p').text # => "foo"
```

I recommend being lazy and using [`search`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search) and [`at`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-at) for 99.9% of the times you write code searching for nodes, then use the CSS/XPath variant for those oh-so-few times when you have to give Nokogiri a hint what the selector is.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!  It seemed we had battling edits going on.  I really like your solution and have updated the edit in my original post accordingly.